# How to create bootstrap custom menu like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new at bootstrap css template. I want to do something like this.
[image]

I have places JSON object. if my place object has sub places like "Hotels", menu shows arrow to accordion and opens sub places. If place object has no sub place, it will show zoom button.

I can not create the css and html design via bootstrap.

Comment: Not sure it will help, but you can use bootswatch which is a nice website for customizing bootstrap. http://bootswatch.com/

Comment: Tried this? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse